# Matlab - Undefined function or variable 'tsne'

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2016b in my Ubuntu laptop. I installed it with all the packages and extensions.

When I try to execute 'tsne' function for ploting the t-SNE embbeding of some data, I receive the error by console:

```
Undefined function or variable 'tsne'
```

What should I do? Reinstall matlab? I have searched at the documentation of the function and it seems to be preinstalled, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tsne](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne.html) was introduced in R2017a.